# с++ рекуррентная последовательность

Tags: c++, математика, ряды, рекуррентность

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите или подтолкните к решению этакой задачи. Пока совсем не понимаю с чего начинать и как это записывать в виде кода. нужно вычистить xi и yi и вставлять это в ряд или может по другому?

Comment: Начните с меньшей задачи - напишите программу, которая печатает Xi

Comment: Попробую , спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишу только потому, что De74ttempt дал свой ответ, так что уже в любом случае решение учебной задачи выдано :)

Люди, ну нельзя же **так** работать - для каждого члена считать свой факториал отдельной функцией, знак получать возведением в степень, для квадрата использовать `pow`,  массивы создавать (кстати, еще и не разрешенным в C++ способом)... Молчу, что факториал при `a == 13` накроется.

```
double Series(int n)
{
    int sign = -1;
    double x    = 1.0, y   = 1.0;
    double fact = 1.0, sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        double z = x;
        x = x + y/i/i;
        y = y + z/i;
        sum += (x + (sign=-sign)*y)/(fact *= i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Я бы посмотрел на ваш вариант , как раз мне нужно без pow и всего остального построить задачу, сижу ломаю голову

Comment: Мне очень помог ваш пример , спасибо вам , что помогли разобраться в задаче

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю вам должно помочь это:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int calcFactorial(int a){ //функция подсчёта факториала
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        res = res * i;
    }
        return res;
}

int main(){
    int n = 3; //задаёте n с начала
    //std::cin >> n; //либо вводите через консоль
    float x[n+1], y[n+1];
    x[1] = 1, y[1] = 1;

    for (int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        x[i] = x[i-1] + y[i-1]/(pow(i, 2));
        y[i] = y[i-1] + x[i-1]/i;
    }

    float sum = 0;
    float result = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sum+=x[i]+(pow(-1, i))*y[i];
        sum/=calcFactorial(i);

        result+=sum;
        sum = 0;
    }

    std::cout << result << std::endl; //вывод результата
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/47iqe)